# AngularJS currency filter on input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following input field

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" ng-model="ceremony.CeremonyFee | number:2">
```

it is showing up correctly but has been disabled. The error I am receiving is "[ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'ceremony.CeremonyFee | number:2' is non-assignable". I understand why it is in error, but do not know how to get this to work on an input field. Thanks.

Comment: And what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

`input` with `ng-model` is for inputting data, `number` filter is for displaying data. As filter values are not bindable, they are not compatible, as you can see. You have to decide what you want to do with that `input`.

Do you want it to be an input? User can input his own number and you only needs to validate? Use i.e. `pattern` attribute:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ceremony.CeremonyFee" pattern="[0-9]+(.[0-9]{,2})?">
```

Do you want it to be an output? User does not need to input his own value? Do not use `ng-model`, use `value` instead:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ceremony.CeremonyFee | number:2}}" readonly>
```

Comment: There is another option that mixes these two: create a directive that displays the second input (with formatted value) and when the user clicks on it it's changed to the first option for edition (using regex pattern). It's an idea that can work if the UI design requires it

Answer (score 0):

As an error states you have got an 'non-assignable' expression in your `ng-model` attribute.

You should use only `ceremony.CeremonyFee`.

| is used on ng-repeat to indicate what expression should be used as filter.

If you want to have that `<input>` populated with initial data in your controller/link you should give it an initial value ex.

```
$scope.ceremony = {
    CeremonyFee: 'My first ceremony'
}
```

And every time your `<input>` element data will be changed CeremonyFee will be updated as well.

Comment: Yeah, new to angular, understanding that. But how would I alter the input of that data? Or would I have to create a new function to work with these fields?

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE:

really I don't understand what you need, but, if you want just that users can insert only two digits you should use a simple html attributes, have a look on `min`, `max`, `step`...

Follows a pure js solution, but I don't suggest something like that!

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = $scope;
  var testValue = 0;
  Object.defineProperty(vm, 'testValue', {
    get: function() { return testValue; },
    set: function(val) {
      val = Number(val);
      
      if(angular.isNumber(val) && (val < 100 && val > 0)) {
        console.log(val);
        testValue = val;
      }
    } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input style="display:block; width: 100%; padding: 1em .5em;" type="number" ng-model="testValue" />
  </div>
</section>
```

---

the `ng-model` directive requires a viewmodel assignable (or bindable) property, so, you cannot add a pipe...

```js
angular.module('test', [])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-init="testValue = 0">
  <label ng-bind="testValue | currency"></label>
  <input style="display:block;" ng-model="testValue" type="number"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand what you are doing, but the label is read only. We are wanting the filter applied to the input field. Possibly on blur, or like a 'mask' from my .net days. If there is a solution for it, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I found and used the solution found on this page.

http://jsfiddle.net/k7Lq0rns/1/

```
    'use strict';
    angular.module('induction').$inject = ['$scope'];
    angular.module('induction').directive('format',['$filter', function ($filter) {
      return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });

            elem.bind('blur', function(event) {
                var plainNumber = elem.val().replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
            });
        }
  };
}]);
```

relatively easy to apply it.